# How to make my image slider to be draggable with mouse and be infinite to slide over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an image slider, and it slides with two buttons. I want it to be draggable or slide with mouse and be infinite to slide. I mean when it comes to end, it slides continuous from first image over and over.

I hope someone could help me...

Here are my codes:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector("[data-slider]");

const track = slider.querySelector("[data-slider-track]");
const prev = slider.querySelector("[data-slider-prev]");
const next = slider.querySelector("[data-slider-next]");

if (track) {
  prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
    next.removeAttribute("disabled");

    track.scrollTo({
      left: track.scrollLeft - track.firstElementChild.offsetWidth,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });

  next.addEventListener("click", () => {
    prev.removeAttribute("disabled");

    track.scrollTo({
      left: track.scrollLeft + track.firstElementChild.offsetWidth,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });

  track.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const trackScrollWidth = track.scrollWidth;
    const trackOuterWidth = track.clientWidth;

    prev.removeAttribute("disabled");
    next.removeAttribute("disabled");

    if (track.scrollLeft <= 0) {
      prev.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }

    if (track.scrollLeft === trackScrollWidth - trackOuterWidth) {
      next.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: charlieUltra;
    src: url(fonts/charlie-display-ultra.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: GreatSejagad;
    src: url(fonts/Great_Sejagad.ttf);
}

.container {
    width: 1355px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.title {
    color: #45f882;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: GreatSejagad;
}

.main_title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: charlieUltra;
    line-height: 80px;
}

section.slider {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #0e0e16;
    height: 100vh;
}

section.slider .title {
    font-size: 42px;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
}

.slider-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: end;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.slide_content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

button.slider__button {
    background: #45f882;
    border: 3px solid #45f882;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #0e0e16;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button.slider__button:hover {
    border: 3px solid #45f882;
    background: transparent;
    color: #45f882;
}

.slide_content p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: charlieUltra;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.slider .btns {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.slider .btns button {
    height: 48px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: none;
    font-family: charlieUltra;
    border: 3px solid #45f882;
    color: #45f882;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.slider .btns button:hover {
    background: #45f882;
    border: 3px solid #45f882;
    color: #0e0e16;
}

.slide:hover {
    border: 3px solid #45f882;
}

.slider {
  --slider-padding: 1rem;
  --slider-column-gap: 1rem;
  --slide-width: 20%;
  --slide-min-width: 15rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__track {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  padding-inline: var(--slider-padding);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: calc(--var(slider-column-gap) * -1);
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.slider__track > * {
  flex: 0 0 var(--slide-width);
  min-width: var(--slide-min-width);
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  padding-right: var(--slider-column-gap);
}

.slider__track::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slider__buttons {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.slider__buttons [disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slide {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid #383c4e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.slideimg {
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Responsive Media Query */
@media (max-width: 1400px){
    .container {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .menu ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .mob-icons {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
    .main_title {
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .main_title {
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    section.slider .title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    button.slider__button {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .slider .btns button {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
    .main_title {
        font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
    }
    section.slider .title {
        font-size: 30px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />
<section class="slider">
  <div class="container">
  
      <div class="slider" data-slider>
      
    <div class="slider-title">
      <div>
        <p class="title">Shop By Category</p>
        <p class="main_title">Our Collections</p>
      </div>
              
      <div class="slider__buttons">
        <button class="slider__button" data-slider-prev disabled>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="slider__button" data-slider-next>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <ul class="slider__track" data-slider-track>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/hunter.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Sky Hunter</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/jett.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Max Jett</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/stone.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>BrimStone</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/raze.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Mad Raze</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/jackie.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Jackie Welles</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/phoenix.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Phoenix</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/yori.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Yorinobu Ara</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/raze.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Mad Raze</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/hunter.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Sky Hunter</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/jett.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Max Jett</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/stone.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>BrimStone</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/raze.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Mad Raze</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/jackie.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Jackie Welles</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/phoenix.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Phoenix</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/yori.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Yorinobu Ara</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/raze.png" class="slideimg" />
          <div class="slide_content">
            <p>Mad Raze</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="btns">
        <button>SHOW ALL</button>
      </div>
      
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I just want 2 things on these image sliders:

1st: to be draggable with mouse.
2nd: to be infinite to slide. (like a loop)

thank to whom help me on this....

Comment: If you make a runnable snippet it is much easier for people to help. And show just enough code to demonstrate the problem. And please explain what the mouse draggable is supposed to do and show the code you have attempted for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making the slider yourself, it would be much more efficient to use a library. When you do it yourself, you'll need to consider many issues such as optimizing code, debugging, and making it responsive. To avoid dealing with these, there are slider libraries available. For example, some slider libraries you can use are:

- Swiper: https://swiperjs.com/
- Slick: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
- Owl: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

By doing a little research on the documentation pages of these libraries, you can easily achieve what you want.

If you still insist on doing it yourself, first, you need to listen for 'mousedown' and 'mouseup' events on the '.slider__track' class to determine which direction the mouse is dragging. For example:

```
let startX, dragLength = 100;

document.querySelector('.slider__track').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  startX = e.offsetX;
});

document.querySelector('.slider__track').addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (e.offsetX - startX > dragLength || e.offsetX - startX > (dragLength * -1)) {//drag length
    if (e.offsetX > startX) {
      //left-to-right
    } else {
      //right-to-left
    }
  }
});
```

To make the slider infinite, you need to dynamically create and maintain an array of 'li' elements. Depending on the scroll position, you need to add and remove elements from the beginning or end of the array to create an infinite loop. For example:

```
let liArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Assume liArr contains the information you'll use.
If the slider will have the 0th index in the middle, the shape of the array should be:

```
liArr = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3];
```

If I slide to the right, the updated array should be:

```
liArr = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

The same should happen when sliding left. You'll need to create elements using document.createElement for each slide action, fill in the relevant places, and then use prepend or append on the '.slider__track' class.

Comment: But what about my codes? nobody can help me on them?

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer any question, it only propose something else to do it, which is not what Op need